# Move files based of a comparison with a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have 1000 files with following names:

something-345-something.txt
something-**5468**-something.txt
something-100-something.txt
something-**6200**-something.txt
and a lot more...

And I have one txt file, with only numbers in it. f.e:

1000
500
**5468

6200**
699
usw...

Now I would like to move all files, which have a number in their filenames which is in my txt file.

So in my example above the following files should be moved only:
something-**5468**-something.txt
something-**6200**-something.txt

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your code, what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about on the fly moving files by doing this:

```
for i in `cat you-file.txt`; do
    find . -iname "*-$i-*" -exec mv '{}' /target/dir \;
; done
```

For every line in your text file, the `find` command will try to find only does matching the pattern `*-$i-*` (something-**6200**-something.txt) and move it to your target dir.

Comment: Nice, short solution. Do not forget the dashes in the wildcard string.

Comment: Worked liked a sharm, even without the dashes :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation: `for file in $(ls); do grep $(echo -n $file | sed -nr 's/[^-]*-([0-9]+).*/\1/p') my-one-txt.txt && mv $file /tmp/somewhere; done`

In English: For every file in output of ls: parse number part of filename with `sed` and grep for it in your text file. `grep` returns a non-zero exit code if nothing is found, so `mv` is in evaluated in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Script file named `move` (executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGETDIR="$1"
FILES=`find . -type f` # build list of files
while read n # read numbers from standard input
do # n contains a number => filter list of files by that number:
  echo "$FILES" | grep "\-$n-" | while read f
  do # move file that passed the filter because its name matches n:
    mv "$f" "$TARGETDIR"
  done
done
```

Use it like this:

```
cd directory-with-files
./move target-directory < number-list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crazy bit of bash hackery

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
mv -t /target/dir *-@($(paste -sd "|" numbers.txt))-*
```

That uses `paste` to join all the lines in your numbers file with pipe characters, then uses [bash extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) to find the files matching any one of the numbers.

I assume `mv` from GNU coreutils for the `-t` option.